# C++ error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, g++

Now I'm trying to install RealPlexor by dklab, but it's falls with errors:

```
# bash ./Make.sh 
In file included from dklab_realplexor.cpp:68:
utils/misc.h: In function ‘void die(std::string)’:
utils/misc.h:105: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Here is that line

```
s = regex_replace(s, regex("\\$!"), [](smatch s) { return strerrno(); });
```

Comment: What's the line preceding this one?

Comment: Your *certain* your toolchain is (a) compiling with c++11 compliance and  (b) supports lamdas ?

Comment: @DavidO void die(string s)
{
    s = regex_replace(s, regex("\\$!"), *(smatch s) { return strerrno(); });
    throw runtime_error(s);
}

Comment: @WhozCraig my server is running on Debian with gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5

Comment: I suspected so. Lambda expression support was not added to g++ until 4.5. Read [**this**](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport), or [**this**](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Comment: Compared to the rate at which C++ has been moving, that's a very very old version of g++.

Comment: @BenVoigt upgraded to gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are passing the following flag to your compiler (as described in the [the g++ documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)):

```
-std=c++11
```

This tells the gcc compiler (g++) to compile your code with C++11 semantics.

The lambda expression syntax you are using (the part starting with `[]`) is a C++11 feature, and will cause compilers great confusion if it appears in code that they aren't expecting to be C++11.

However, as has been pointed out in another comment here (and is confirmed by [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport), the version of gcc you are running (4.4.5, per a comment) doesn't have lambda expression support.  May have to use a function object instead, or upgrade to a newer version of gcc/g++.

Comment: Don't work, falls with `# bash ./Make.sh 
In file included from dklab_realplexor.cpp:68:0:
utils/misc.h: In function ‘void die(std::string)’:
utils/misc.h:105:50: error: expected primary-expression before ‘s’
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
`

Comment: If you're still experiencing the error after upgrading g++ to 4.7, then you're not using the `-std=c++11` flag as documented in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html , and judging from some of your other comments, I would say you probably need to set Make.sh to generate the appropriate flags in the project's makefile.

Comment: For example, create the simplest C++11 program you can, that uses some simple C++11 feature.  Compile it with `g++ -std=c++11 mytest.cpp -o mytest`, and you can confirm for yourself in a simpler environment that the compiler flag works.

Answer (score 0):

Just say

```
s = regex_replace(s, regex("\\$!"), *(smatch s) { return strerrno(); });
```

The `[]` operator is usually used to index something (like a character array), so C++ expects something in front of it

Also try this suggestion from @DavidO:

You're using a lambda expression which is a C++11 syntax, but probably haven't set your compiler to recognize C++11. If you're using g++, you would use the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: now its falls with `# bash ./Make.sh 
In file included from dklab_realplexor.cpp:68:
utils/misc.h: In function ‘void die(std::string)’:
utils/misc.h:105: error: expected primary-expression before ‘s’
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
`

Comment: Is using `*(smatch s){ return strerrno(); }` a new way to specify lambdas in C++?

Comment: I am not sure, I have never used C++11

Comment: There you go; you're using a lambda expression which is a C++11 syntax, but probably haven't set your compiler to recognize C++11.  If you're using g++, you would use the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: I'll add that in my answer

Comment: I see. As far as I can tell, lambdas are introduced by `[]` (see 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda], specifically the syntax for _lambda-introducer_ which reads: `[` _lambda-capture-opt_ ']'

Comment: @DavidO ok, now I'm updating `gpp` package, and `apt-get` now installing c++11 lib

Comment: @KirillDanshin Great, I've summarized this conclusion in an answer.

Comment: @DavidO no, it's doesn't works. 1)there's no `-std=c++11` flag in g++, and I've replaced its to `-std=c++0x`, and it's falls again with the same error in console.

Comment: @KirillDanshin You are incorrect about there not being a `-std=c++11` in `g++` version 4.7.2.  Or are you saying the documentation and my own use of that flag is wrong? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html  You need to make sure your makefile is configured to use that flag.  That exceeds the scope of your question, however.